# Install minimal Rust setup on Debian

Tags: debian, disk-usage, rust

I would like to run [this Rust script](https://github.com/matrix-org/rust-synapse-compress-state/issues/13) on my Matrix server but it uses 1.8GB space to build it:

```
$ du -shc .rustup/ .cargo/ /var/www/rust-synapse-compress-state/
1,2G    .rustup/
86M     .cargo/
561M    /var/www/rust-synapse-compress-state/
1,8G    total
```

I found [this CI script that installs Rust on AWS](https://github.com/lambci/lambci/blob/master/home/init/rust). Could I use this to install a minimal Rust version in my Debian VM where I am low on disk-space? What are the needed bash commands to install this package on Debian? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you’re using Debian, you could use the Rust packages instead:

```
sudo apt install cargo
```

This will reduce the requirements significantly compared to the 1.2GiB taken by `.rustup`.

On Debian 10 this will give you Rust 1.34 which is sufficient to build `rust-synapse-compress-state`.

Comment: I had to upgrade to Debian 10 to get a reasonable new Rust version